# PDF preview not working with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: lyx, pdf, viewers, adobe

I am using LyX 2.1. However, I cannot preview the output in PDF. This happens after I updated from Acrobat Reader 11 to Acrobat Reader DC (if I am not mistaken, it is version 15). What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the path to AR DC is correct?

Comment: Many LyX users using Windows have reported success with using SumatraPDF. It is free and open source and seems to work better than Acrobat.